# Android 4.4 How can I prevent non default sms application to receive sms

Tags: android

Well I know that starting from 4.4 version of Android there is a concept of default sms application and as it is written in docs:

> "any attempt by your app to abort the SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION broadcast will be ignored so all apps interested have the chance to receive it."

I'm wondering is it possible to somehow prevent other sms applications to receive incoming sms, like immediately remove from DB or other trick. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.